# VBA MS Access OpenReport with Where clause issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an issue with my VBA code. I tried to use Where condition in a OpenReport to filter in my table all my mice alives.

The code I used:

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "E_G_Mouse", acViewReport,, [statut]="Alive"
```

The output is just like I didn't use where condition.

When I use macro Open Report with the same where condition, it works. I prefer to write my DB in VBA. Why it's worked with the macro, not VBA code?

Comment: The where clause needs to be a string, and I'm pretty sure you don't want the brackets around the field name. So `"statut = Alive"`

Comment: Is field name actually `statut` or is it `status`?

Answer (score 0):

The criteria needs to be a string within quote marks. Brackets `[ ]` are needed if object names use space or punctuation/special characters or are reserved words (otherwise using doesn't hurt). Use apostrophe delimiters for text field parameters, # for date/time, nothing for number.

`DoCmd.OpenReport "E_G_Mouse", acViewReport, , "[statut]='Alive'"`

If you want variable input of parameter, concatenate.

`DoCmd.OpenReport "E_G_Mouse", acViewReport, , "statut='" & Me.controlname & "'"`